# explanation of firebase docs about query(query, queryConstraints)?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I was looking about more details about the query function in firestore in [docs reference of firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#functions) and I found this pseudo syntax :

```
query(query, queryConstraints)
```

but in all firestore examples about this function they used in the first parameter a collection reference not **query**

form firestore examples :

```
// Create a reference to the cities collection
import { collection, query, where } from "firebase/firestore";
const citiesRef = collection(db, "cities");

// Create a query against the collection.
const q = query(citiesRef, where("state", "==", "CA"));
```

Is it the same function or this is another Signature for it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A collection reference is a subclass of a query, so wherever the API expects a `Query` you can also pass a `CollectionReference`. So you can build a new query by passing a `CollectionReference` to the `query` function, or add conditions to an existing query by passing a `Query` to it.

Comment: Well... `Query` objects are immutable, so what you're doing is creating a new `Query` based on an existing one.